# Is it intended for The Overflow newsletter to be auto opt-in?

Tags: support, profile-page, email, newsletter, the-overflow

There's been a notice on Stack Overflow that **The Overflow** has been launched today, after reading [the associated blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/01/introducing-overflow-newsletter-cassidy-williams/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=announcement-banner&utm_campaign=the-overflow-newsletter&utm_content=october-launch), and specifically the following part:

> If you want to subscribe to The Overflow, log into your Stack Overflow account and head over to your email preferences. If you got the email and don’t feel like getting it again, you can head to your email preferences and opt out.

However, when visiting the email preferences for the first time since registration, it seemed that I was already subscribed to The Overflow. Further asking in chat confirmed that multiple others also had an automatic opt in.

The question would be, is the *intended* behavior? If so, why does the blog post suggest opting in?

Comment: FWIW I was not auto opted in. Kevin B mentioned something about it in chat and I immediately went to go look (along with checking my inbox) and it was toggled "off" (and I had no email in my inbox). NB - I am only signed up for research emails and nothing else.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a group of people who signed up to receive occasional emails from Stack Overflow. In the past that has included company news, community announcements, product updates. Folks who opted into this bucket will get The Overflow, which is a new product with a mix of company, community, and content.

We also want new folks who are interested to subscribe, which is why we explained how folks can opt-in. They might be people who don't have an SO account, or SO account owners who had chosen not to receive any email from us in the past.

Lastly, we of course want everyone to feel free to easily opt-out if The Overflow is not something they want to receive. You can unsubscribe from the email or opt-out from your email preferences if you're logged into SO.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It would help if that was made explicit somewhere. :-) without your explanation it looked like a bug to me. *If you opted in to occasional announcements before, you are already opted in*.

Comment: Fair point, I will edit the blog now to clarify.

Comment: I didn't expect "occasional" to become *regular*. The email you should have sent was an announcement of whatever this is, not "Issue #1" directly.

Comment: @muru That’s fair. On the flip side, this way you know exactly what you’ll be getting if you stick with it. It’s both a new feature announcement and an example. So we figured sending that but also making it a separate email category you can opt out of was a reasonable combination.

Comment: While I'm interested in new features, I'm not at all interested in spam or newsletter like many call it.

Comment: @AdamLear No, that was not a reasonable combination. Make it a separate category, fine. Make a banner that asks people to subscribe to the newsletter. Fine. Make it something that most everybody gets and say it's "opt out" - that is what's commonly called **spamming people**.

Comment: I flagged it as phishing/spam. A few minutes later a comment on Twitter made me wonder what is going on and then I found this here. Definitely not cool to subscribe me to a newsletter without asking.

Comment: Please don't equate "Signed up to receive occasional emails" to auto-subscribing to a new class of emails that you just created. This should've been opt-in not opt-out.

Comment: @deepakg I mean, on the other hand, what actually counts as "occasional" emails? A monthly newsletter would be 12 emails a year which definitely seems occasional to me. Or specifically "on occasion"  such as "hey we have a new blog post".

Comment: @TylerH - Firstly, this is a biweekly newsletter - so 24 emails a year. Secondly, the original "occasional" Features & Announcements email is still around. That's definitely way over my threshold for "occasional".

Comment: @TylerH - Also, the original Features & Announcements has definitely been way less frequent (more like less than once a quarter), But setting aside our differences over semantics of "occasional" - I am not ok with being auto-subscribed to newsletters without my explicit consent.

Comment: @deepakg I assume you mean bi-monthly as bi-weekly would imply 108 emails per year.

Comment: @Roberrrt bi-weekly can mean "every two weeks" or "twice a week", so their "24" can be correct..

Comment: Why should I opt out of a newsletter subscription I didn't made?

Comment: @Tom Probably an arithmetic error. With 52 weeks in a year at once every 2 weeks, it'd be 25+1 = 26, and I suspect they accidentally subtracted the 1 instead. That or a straight up typo.